# Convert Rxjs code to Angular 6 and latest rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

**Scenario :**

- New to Angular
  Trying to **migrate Angular 2 code into Angular 6**.
- Any idea how I
  can rewrite the following code in angular 6

**Code To write in Angular 6 :**

```
return this._http.post(this.apiBaseUrl + "/api/login", body, options)
   .timeoutWith(Constant.timeout, Observable.throw(new Error(Constant.timeoutMsg)))
      .map(response => {
            const result = response.json() as LoginResultModel;

            if (result.AccessToken != null) {
                this.setLoginToken(result);
                return result;
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Kindly have a look at [Update Angular](https://update.angular.io/) site and see what changes you should be doing for migration

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Please do not add noise like Open to all suggestions, Please suggest. Thank You. These edits should be rejected and will be reversed. They are not useful. We do not put stuff like that to questions at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `pipe` method and put both `timeoutWith` and `map` operators as functions as its parameters:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, timeoutWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this._httpClient.post<LoginResultModel>(this.apiBaseUrl + "/api/login", body, options)
  .pipe(
    timeoutWith(Constant.timeout, throwError(new Error(Constant.timeoutMsg))),
    map(result => {
      if (result.AccessToken != null) {
        this.setLoginToken(result);
        return result;
      } else {
        return response;
      }
    })
  );
```

More about pipable operators in RxJS 6:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Note I also used `HttpClientModule`, where you don't need to use `response.json()` method, more about that here:

https://angular.io/guide/http